# How likely is a hyperparameter search on a subset dataset going to be accurate on the full dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, hyperparameter

I'm running a hyper parameter search over many options in a neural network, holding all but one fixed in turn until I come to rest on a reasonably optimal set of hyperparameters.

I wonder if anyone has any insight on how well a *subset of the full dataset* will be representative of the full dataset in this process?

For example, if I have a 1M item dataset these trainings may very well take on the order of days, weeks, or longer. If I sample 10,000 items out of that dataset, how reasonable/unreasonable is it to hope that the hyperparameters I identify for this subset will be equally optimal when run on the full dataset?